# FxCop: get custom dictionary work from command line

Tags: fxcopcmd

I can't find the answer here or in google. I'm trying to do the simplest - having CustomDictionary.xml in a solution subfolder (this is a requirement) and FxCop installed via copying it to build server (requirement too) i need to run FxCopCmd analysis using custom dictionary.

It works fine except that fxcopcmd just doesn't get custom dictionary no matter what I pass in the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever mechanism you're using for specifying the target assembly path(s) should work equally well for the dictionary path.  Failing that, you can use the placeholder `%fxcop%` to represent the directory from which you are running fxcopcmd.exe in a relative path.  e.g.:

```
"D:\BuildFolder\Tools\FxCopCmd.exe" ... /dictionary:"%fxcop%\..\CustomDictionary.xml"
```